# Using non-FUJITSU 10Gb Ethernet Cards in FUJITSU servers

Tags: networking, 10gbethernet, pci-express

We are currently trying to upgrade old servers to 10Gb connections. The servers in question are:

- PRIMERGY RX200 S6
- PRIMERGY RX300 S5

Our FUJITSU partner told us that there were no cards available by FUJITSU. There seem to be cards available by 3rd-party-manufacturers though. The PCIe slots in the servers seem to be PCIe 2.0 x8.

Should we expect any problems running non-FUJITSU cards in the servers?

Comment: We don't do product recommendations, thus I've removed that part of your question. For the other part: This should work. At the very least, we don't have any problems with 3rd party NICs (not 10 GB) and FC HBAs in our Primergy servers.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, sorry. Thanks for your reply.